# adding a view's to an existing subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a delegate which basically adds a view controller's view to this view's as a subview. The issue is that the background of the subview is always gray. I've set it so that the color is clear. Any idea why? I want it to be see through.

```
- (void)fullStryViewController:(FullStryViewController *)fullStoryVC addFullScreenSubView:(UIViewController *) viewController
{
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

Comment: Have you set the colour of the view to which you are adding your clear-colour view to be clear as well?

Comment: yes I actually did... before that there was some view

Comment: How are you setting the colours of both views?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this way ?,

```
- (void)fullStryViewController:(FullStryViewController *)fullStoryVC addFullScreenSubView:(UIViewController *) viewController
{
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```